# Combine Mobile and Screen function

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to get this function to work properly. The toggleNav works on it's own. I want to apply different Open/close functionality based on screen size. the navigation opens and closes based on mouse events, so the code needs to continuously run at each screen size.

```
 let opened = false; // set the nav as closed by default

if ($(window).width() > 720) {
  function toggleNav() {
    if(!opened) { // if opened is false (ie nav is closed), open the nav
    openNav()
  } else { // else, if opened is ture (ie nav is open), close the nav
    closeNav();
  }
 opened = !opened; // negate boolean to get opposite (t to f, and f to t)
  }
}else{
 function toggleNav2() {
  if(!opened) { 
   openNav2()
  } else { 
   closeNav2();
  }
opened = !opened; 
}
}

function openNav() {
  $('#myTopnav').addClass('openHeight').removeClass('closeHeight');
   $('#main').addClass('openMain').removeClass('closeMain');
}

function closeNav() {
   $('#myTopnav').removeClass('openHeight').addClass('closeHeight');
  $('#main').removeClass('openMain').addClass('closeMain');
}

function openNav2() {
  $('#main').addClass('openMain').removeClass('closeMain');
}

function closeNav2() {
 $('#main').removeClass('openMain').addClass('closeMain');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're asking how to make this work in the event that the user resizes their view.

I would recommend rearranging your styles so that there is one master class that controls this feature, on a single parent element (e.g.: `body`), which you can then toggle on and off via javascript. In this way, all style changes (including those caused by user view size changes) are handled by CSS and javascript only has to manage a single element.

You don't provide enough of your code to rework what you're doing but, as an example (click "expand snippet" and resize your browser window as needed to experiment with the width):

```js
$('button').on('click', e => {
  $('body').toggleClass('off');
});
```

```css
.top:after {
  display:block;
  content:"on";
  color: #080;
}
.bottom:after {
  display:block;
  content:"on";
  color: #080;
}

/* overrides for "off" state */
.off .top:after {
  content:"off";
  color: #800;
}
/* only override css if view width > 720px */
@media (min-width:721px) {
  .off .bottom:after {
    content:"off";
    color: #800;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">toggle</button>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: That seems like a good approach, The event I had previously was to apply styles based on a user event but would be different based on screen size. The functionality wasn't as important, just needed to know how to apply it correctly. thank you